# How to advance iteration while inside an iterator spreadsheet rows

Tags: python, excel, iteration, xlrd

I need to advance the iteration of rows read from and excel spreadsheet while still inside the iterator loop.

```
try:
    for r in range(insheet.nrows):
        cdat = insheet.cell(r, 0).value
        if not cdat == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
            if hasNumbers(cdat):
                #Strip digits to get Client pneumonic
                #pdb.set_trace()
                if re.sub(r'\d','',cdat) == CLNTID:
                    #pdb.set_trace()
                    #This call belongs to this client
                    memId = cdat
                    fInCallBlock = True
                    while fInCallBlock:
                        #Output this line formatted as CallHeader
                        #Inc row counter
    Can't do this ==>   next(r)
                        cdat = cdat.strip(insheet.cell(r, 0).value) 
                        if cdat == u"Call Resolved":
                            pdb.set_trace()
                            fInCallBlock = False
```

the code crashes where marked with:

```
-> next(r)
(Pdb++) n
TypeError: 'int object is not an iterator'
```

and I just cannot find out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `range` to a variable and then advance it

```
myrange = iter(range(insheet.rows))

for r in myrange:

    ...
    next(myrange)
```

Of course that `range` works that way in Python 3. If still under Python 2 it would be `xrange`

Beware that the `r` value will not change unless you not only advance the iterator but also assign the ouput of it to `r`:

```
r = next(myrange)
```

You should also cath the potential `StopIteration` exception which may be raised when advancing the `range`

Comment: In python 2 `xrange` is not an iterator, you have to explicitly define it as such `myrange=iter(xrange(insheet.rows))`

Comment: Also, are you sure `range` is an iterator in python 3? I only have python 2 in this machine so I can't test it, but I think you also need to define it as such

Comment: Same issue in Python 3 (3.4.2): must wrap `range()` in `iter()`.

Answer (score 0):

`r` is an integer from the `range()`, not an iterator, so you can't call `next()` on it.

You could use a `while` loop with a counter instead of the `for` loop:

```
try:
    r = 0
    while r < insheet.nrows:
        cdat = insheet.cell(r, 0).value
        if not cdat == xlrd.empty_cell.value:
            if hasNumbers(cdat):
                #Strip digits to get Client pneumonic
                #pdb.set_trace()
                if re.sub(r'\d','',cdat) == CLNTID:
                    #pdb.set_trace()
                    #This call belongs to this client
                    memId = cdat
                    r += 1
                    while r < insheet.nrows:
                        #Output this line formatted as CallHeader
                        cdat = cdat.strip(insheet.cell(r, 0).value) 
                        if cdat == u"Call Resolved":
                            break
                        #Inc row counter
                        r += 1
        r += 1
```